# Any drawbacks publishing aab app bundles to google play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

As the title says.

Of course I would like to reduce my package size, but I am a bit sceptical regarding automated packaging for specific devices.

Thats why I am asking people here, which already publish aab and maybe can confirm, that all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a software engineer who works on the App Bundle.

At 0:35 in [this video](https://youtu.be/flhib2krW7U) from I/O, you can see a sample of the apps who have adopted the App Bundle in production, including Google apps. This is now widely adopted.

The main problems that developers are facing in the transition from APK to App Bundle are the changes in their testing process (and continuous builds), and makes their app less easy to sideload -- some developers have seen crashes from users sideloading only the base APK without all the required config split APKs, but these will reduce slowly.

On an additional note, you can always try and go back to APKs if for some reason it doesn't work for you.

Comment: does this support shared apps?

Comment: What do you mean by shared apps? Apps sharing code or data across process? Or sharing apps across devices? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierre. You mentoined "you can always try", but I can't try on all devices. Do you mean with trying : publishing to beta and if it works on my 3 devices, then I can go for prod ?

Comment: You could also start in a closed beta, open beta, or with a progressive rollout (e.g. start with 1% of your users, then increase at 5%, etc.) until you're satisfied with the results.